# Lazy loading calculated property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I using lazy loading, but in my "calculated" property Amount have 'System.NullReferenceException' when i try to access to related property
any idea?

```
public class SalesLine
{
    public int LineNo { get; set; }
    public int DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get { return Quantity * Item.UnitPrice; } set { } }
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

var lines = context.SalesLine.ToList();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a setter that does nothing.  If there's no value to set, then don't have a setter at all.

Comment: As for NRE, although your property is *eligible* for lazy loading, are you sure lazy loading (and proxy creation) is enabled for your `context`?

Comment: yes, its enabled